# Quotation mark in ConTeXt

Tags: formatting, context

I try to compile a document in `ConTeXt` in which the main language is greek. However, when i try to quote a phrase using `\quote{}` command i get an error.

If however, i change the main language of my document to english (`\mainlanguage[en]`), the error disappears.

So, i guess that i need somehow to define quotation marks. Since, i am new in `ConTeXt`, i would appreciate any help

Comment: You are a member of the community for quite some time and should know by now that you should *always* post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is is be much easier when we see compilable code.

Comment: I didn't post a mwe because i knew that `ConTeXt` couldn't recognize quotation marks when greek is the main language. However, I didn't know how to define quotation marks. But you are right, i should post a mwe for anyone's convenience and willingness to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think somebody forgot to define `\greekleftquot` and `\greekrightquot`.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Greek) the Greek language uses guillemots for quotes.  These are readily available and can be used to define the missing macros.

```
% these were forgotten
\def\greekleftquot {\leftguillemot }
\def\greekrightquot{\rightguillemot}

\mainlanguage[gr]

\setupbodyfont[computer-modern-unicode]% font with greek script

\starttext

\quotation{Νέα Ελληνικά}

\stoptext
```

[image]